# Wordpress read RSS full article

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, feed

I'm using PHP simpleXML_load_file command to load a WordPress Feed , however I see only a summary of the article and not the whole of it.

example : http://www.tenditrendy.com/wp-rss2.php

I've learned that it might be related to "show full text" configuration or to some plugin that are installed at WordPress , is that so?

what shall I do in order to read the full article and not just a summary?

Comment: Go to Settings->Reading->"For each article in a feed, show" - here you should be able to select "Full text". If that doesn't work, tell us what plugins you have installed.

Comment: Selecting Full text helped , yet - I'm only crawling the feed to get the article content , I dont want the followers of post to see whole article (right now , they see only description and urged to press on the link and see full article) - How do I keep follower seeing short description , while my PHP crawler would see the full content ?